# How to find the phase difference of two sampled sine waves?

Tags: list-manipulation, signal-processing

I'm trying to measure a phase difference between two Sine functions I've acquired with a computer. I'm uploading one of the .txt files with the data I'm working with here: [txt file](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?20zc13hbf436r81). To remove the units of every row I'm using the function that @R.M posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/replace-values-of-a-list-containing-words-and-numbers).

The first two columns of each file make a Sin function, the other columns make a different one. Here's a plot of those functions togheter:

[image: Two Sin functions with different pahses.]

I'm looking for a way to find all rows that have a maximum value on the second coordinate (that is, second and fourth column) and then be able to manipulate those lists in order to get the difference between the other two coordinates. For example, if this are the two lists with the maximums:

```
max1={{1.1,6},{2.2,6},{3.3,6},{4.4,6}{5.5,6}}
max2={{1.3,10},{2.4,10}{3.5,},{4.6,10},{5.7,10}}
```

Then I could easily get the difference between the first coordinates of each pair (1.3-1.1, 2.4-2.2, etc.), which is what I need.

I have tried doing the proposed methods in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/900/how-to-find-rows-that-have-maximum-value) but none of them worked for me.

Furthermore, I got a lot of files like this to analyze, so I'm importing all of them with a For loop and putting them all on the same list with `Table`. It would be nice if I could get the maximums of all my files at the same time.

I'll apreciate any ideas, thank you.

Ps.: By the way, by asking and reading the contents of this page I realized Mathematica is a much more powerful tool than I thought, and I would like to learn more about how to properly use it. I know the Mathematica documentation is really good, but I would like to get a good book about Mathematica. Do you know one to reccommend?

Comment: For links to good books and introductions to Mathematica, you might try starting here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: Why don't you post your datafile already converted to a Mathematica list?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If what you really want to do is to find the phase difference between two digitized sinusoids of the same frequency, then there is probably a better way to proceed than by counting the peaks. You can take the Fourier transform of the two signals, and then look at the phase difference between them. For example, say the sine waves are:

```
s1 = Table[Sin[2 Pi 10 t], {t, -1, 2, 1/1000}];
s2 = Table[0.2 Sin[2 Pi 10 t + 0.8], {t, -1, 2, 1/1000}];
ListLinePlot[{s1, s2}]
```

So you can see this is qualitatively like your situation. I've arbitrarily assigned the second (smaller) sine wave to be 0.8 radians out of phase with the first. Let's take the FFTs and recover this from the data.

```
ffts1 = Fourier[s1, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
ffts2 = Fourier[s2, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
max = Max[Abs[ffts1]];
pos = First[First[Position[Abs[ffts1], max]]];
Arg[ffts1[[pos]]] - Arg[ffts2[[pos]]]
```

which gives the answer

```
0.800167
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this right away.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, this is just what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

A simple and fast method for finding the phase difference would be to do it manually. Let's plot the two data sets in a `Manipulate` and let one have a manually determined offset. Since the time bases in both lists are the same I discard them for the moment so that the x-axis depicts sample number:

```
Manipulate[
    ListLinePlot[{24.7 lists[[1, All, 2]], lists[[2, offset ;; -1, 2]]}, ImageSize -> 600], 
    {offset, 1, 400, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I scaled one of the plots by 24.7 for reasons that will be made clear later on.

If you play with that you find that a 38 sample shift is about optimal.

How to do this with fourier analysis?

The  amplitude spectra:

```
af1 = Abs@Fourier[lists[[1, All, 2]]];
af2 = Abs@Fourier[lists[[2, All, 2]]];
```

The phases:

```
pf1 = Arg@Fourier[lists[[1, All, 2]]];
pf2 = Arg@Fourier[lists[[2, All, 2]]];
```

A plot of the amplitude spectrum of the first sample:

```
ListLinePlot[af1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The two peaks are at:

```
Ordering[af1, -2]
```

> {14, 2488}

The same for the second sample. At position 14 the ratio of the amplitudes is:

```
af2[[14]]/af1[[14]]
```

> 24.70345393

So, here we have our amplitude scaling factor.

The phase difference for this peak is:

```
pf2[[14]] - pf1[[14]]
```

> 1.240647232

or in terms of sample positions:

```
(pf2[[14]] - pf1[[14]])/(2 \[Pi]) 1/((14.-1)/Length[af1])
```

> 37.97214223

Yes, the same value we found manually.

Comment: A good way of solving this, but I have a lot of lists (90 or so). Though I'm sure it will prove useful some time.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes Correlation is useful too:

```
l1 = Table[Sin[x] + RandomReal[1/10], {x, 0, 10 Pi, 1/20}];
l2 = 1/4 Table[Sin[x + 1/2] + RandomReal[1/15], {x, 0, 10 Pi, 1/20}];
ListPlot[{l1, l2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now:

```
h = IntegerPart[Length@l1/4]; 
lc = N@ListCorrelate[l1[[h - # ;; -h - #]], l2[[h ;; -h]]][[1]] & /@ Range[h - 1];
ListPlot[{RotateRight[l1, First@Ordering[lc] - 1], l2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Running with your data:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And the offset is

```
First@Ordering[lc] - 1
(*137 *)
```

or 2.74 μS

Comment: Correlation is great, but two comments apropos this solution: (1) You appear to have found the *minimum* correlation: the two datasets are completely out of phase in your images.  Usually we want the maximum correlation. (2) Applying an interpolating function to each dataset will enable you automatically to pin down the phase shift to high precision.

Comment: Thanks Whuber. Re:1) I use correlation this way because (and this is just an experimental result, I can't prove it) I usually find the minimum better defined than the maximum. 2) I don't quite understand why using interpolation on noisy data is a good thing, surely I'm missing something there.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of interpolating the *data* (although in retrospect I see it sounds like that), but rather wanted to suggest interpolating the correlogram.  Your point about noise is a good one, regardless: the correlogram can usually be improved by first smoothing (or filtering) the data.  There's a decent discussion of this in the appropriate Numerical Recipes chapter.

Comment: @whuber Ah, Ok. Agree. I misunderstood you

Answer (score 9):

```
Correlation[s1, s2] // ArcCos
```

Borrowing @bills definitions

```
s1 = N@Table[Sin[2 Pi 10 t], {t, -1, 2, 1/1000}];
s2 = N@Table[0.2 Sin[2 Pi 10 t + 0.8], {t, -1, 2, 1/1000}];
```

You get

> 0.800166

Borrowing @belisarius 's

```
s1 = Table[Sin[x] + RandomReal[1/10], {x, 0, 10 Pi, 1/20}];
s2 = 1/4 Table[Sin[x + 1/2] + RandomReal[1/15], {x, 0, 10 Pi, 1/20}];

Correlation[s1, s2] // ArcCos
```

> 0.501371

Comment: It's seem the `Correlation` don't work in [this case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141636/21532) or I have missed something?

Comment: @yode well, this is to estimate the phase difference between 2 harmonic signals and the other question is about aligning 2 general signals, right?

Comment: Thanks fro explanation,I'm a new commer in signal-processing

Answer (score 5):

Using my function from [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10914/replace-values-of-a-list-containing-words-and-numbers) and the file you've provided, first import the data and group the first two columns and the last two columns as:

```
data = convertList /@ Import["/path/to/RLC1.txt", "Data"] /. {} -> Sequence[];
lists = Transpose /@ Partition[Transpose@data, 2];
```

You can plot them simply as `ListPlot[lists]`. To find the rows that have the maximum element in the second position, you can choose from `Cases` or `Pick` or `Select`. I like `Select`, and we can write a function that takes a list and returns those rows that have the maximum value in the second column:

```
maxList[list_List] := With[{max = Max@list[[;; , 2]]}, Select[list, #[[2]] == max &]];

maxList@First@lists // Short
(* {{-22.8,0.3},{-22.78,0.3},{-22.76,0.3},{-22.74,0.3},{-22.72,0.3},<<128>>,
    {24.24,0.3},{24.26,0.3},{24.28,0.3},{24.34,0.3},{24.36,0.3}} *)

maxList@Last@l // Short
(* {{-22.1,7.4},{-22.08,7.4},{-22.06,7.4},{-22.04,7.4},{-22.02,7.4},<<165>>,
    {24.9,7.4},{24.92,7.4},{24.94,7.4},{24.96,7.4},{24.98,7.4}} *)
```

You can get the corresponding rows for both lists as `maxList /@ lists`. With these in hand, you can easily manipulate it however you want. They're both of different lengths, so you'll have to decide how exactly you want to compare the two.

For several files, you can use `FileNames` to filter the data files, wrap the above commands in a [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) and map them across your file list.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to execute the maxList function. It says Syntax::sntxf: ";;" cannot be followed by ",2".
Apart from that, this seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: @Juan I don't get that error... can you try it in a fresh kernel? Perhaps it's due to some earlier definitions...

Comment: Still the same error. If I remove the "," from Max@list[[;; , 2]] the line executes without problems.

Comment: Well, then it gets a different part of the expression. Are you using it on your own list or my example above? It relies on the particular structure of the list (I've already separated it into two lists, each with two columns...)

Comment: I used @bill s approach, but I like your answer. Actually, I think this will prove useful for another purpose I'll have to deal so thank you.