# How to calculate the amount of offset about two list

Tags: list-manipulation, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

You can get my data by this code

```
{data1, data2} = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode@
   Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSMY.png"], "Byte"]]];
```

We can show it with `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Note the peaks of `data1` and `data2` is not same totally.I want to calculate the amount of offset in x-axis direction *after we align `data1` and `data2` as far as possible*.This current try

```
offset = Length[data1] - 
   SmithWatermanSimilarity @@ (PeakDetect[Last /@ #] & /@ {data1,data2});
First[Commonest[Differences[First /@ data1]]]*offset
```

> 17.4

As we can see,the error is very big.I think two diffcult in this solution result to this

- The x-interval is not exactly same.

  ```
  Union[Differences[First /@ data1]]
  ```

  > `{0.01,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.03,0.03}(*funny to get so many 0.02.*)`
- The peak is not exactly same.

[image]

Is there any better method can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could also use `ListCorrelate`.

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode@
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSMY.png"], 
      "Byte"]]];
```

We remove the x axis values for now.

```
data1b = data1[[All, 2]];
data2b = data2[[All, 2]];
lc = 
  Reverse[Chop[ListCorrelate[data1b, data2b, {-1, -1}, 0]]];
maxPos = Ordering[lc, -1][[1]]
```

(* Out[98]= 33 *)

So we want to push the second set by 33-1 = 32 units along the +x axis. We'll see how that looks.

```
ListLinePlot[{data1b, Join[Take[data2b, maxPos - 1], data2b]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

One might wish to preprocess to remove the lower values, and possibly clip high ones. I used the code below for that purpose. In this case it did not change the outcome.

```
reScale[data_] := Module[{mn = Mean[data], newd},
  newd = Clip[Threshold[data - Mean[data], mn/2], {0, mn/2}]]

data1c = reScale[data1b];
data2c = reScale[data2b];
```

--- edit ---

I should remark that what I did is quite similar to the (arguably more scientific) approach shown by @mikado. If I did not zero-pad the `ListCorrelate` the list plot would be identical, up to a constant scale factor, to that of `cc` in the @mikado response.

--- end edit ---

Comment: `ListCorrelate` is a simpler approach in this case and I recommend this answer

Comment: It's simpler, yes, but I'm not sure it is quite correct at least in padding choice. I think one can argue that it works well provided the "correct" shift is small relative to the number of points.

Answer (score 5):

We can use Fourier techniques (cross-correlation) to estimate a misalignment between the signals.

Import the data

```
{data1, data2} = 
  Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode@
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSMY.png"], 
      "Byte"]]];
```

The sample times associated with the two signals are the same

```
(First /@ data1) === (First /@ data2)
(* True *)
```

The sampling rate is close enough to uniform not to cause problems.  The average sample interval is given by

```
dt = Mean[Differences[First /@ data1]]
(* 0.02 *)
```

Compute spectra, subtracting off the pedestal first.

```
spec[u_List] := Fourier[u - Median[u]]
spec1 = spec[Last /@ data1];
spec2 = spec[Last /@ data2];
```

Now compute the cross-correlation

```
cc = InverseFourier[Conjugate[spec2] spec1];
```

The cross-correlation has a clear peak

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{Range[-100, 99] dt, 
   Abs[Join[Take[cc, -100], Take[cc, 100]]]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Cross-correlation peak]

This suggests that the delay is given by about

```
delay = First[First[(Position[Abs[cc], Max[Abs[cc]]] - 1) dt]]
(* 0.64 *)
```

Apply this delay to the data

```
shift[u_List, t_] := {t, 0} + # & /@ u
graph = ListLinePlot[{shift[data1, -32 dt], data2}, PlotRange -> All];
GraphicsColumn[{
  Show[graph, PlotRange -> {{18, 24}, {0, 1000}}], 
  Show[graph, PlotRange -> {{36, 42}, {0, 3500}}], 
  Show[graph, PlotRange -> {{58, 64}, {0, 2500}}],
  Show[graph, PlotRange -> {{78, 84}, {0, 1000}}]}]
```

[image: Aligned sequences]

We can see that the alignment is not perfect - it looks as if the delay may be somewhat variable.

Comment: Just an ask,[this](http://mmascript.com/) is your site?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't recognise any of the characters on that site!

Comment: Just make a note,`MaximalBy[Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity][[1, 1]], Last]` also can give `0.64`.This is a wonderful answer for me.I will accept it after some opening time.Thanks very very much.